# How to reuse pipeline stages with aggregation in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building query pipeline with Aggregate method in Mongoose, I need to reuse some stages for different cases like get all photos and get detail photo, except that I add some stages, the remaining stages are unchanged. How do I keep my code from having to be repetitive to ensure reusability?

Get Photo List:

```
PhotoModel.aggregate()
          .match({ deleted: false })
          .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
          .limit(10)
          .lookup({
             from: 'users',
             localField: 'userId',
             foreignField: '_id',        
             as: 'createdBy',
          })
          .unwind('$createdBy')      
          .lookup({
             from: 'conversations',
             localField: '_id',
             foreignField: 'conversationId',       
             as: 'conversations',
          })
          .unwind({
             path: '$conversations',
             preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          })
          .project({
             _id: 0,
             id: '$_id',
             photoDescription: 1,
             photoUrl: 1,
             createdBy: '$createdBy',
             conversations: '$conversations',
             createdAt: 1,
          });
```

Get Photo Detail:

```
PhotoModel.aggregate()
          .match({ 
              deleted: false, 
              _id: req.params.id   // <====== added condition field here
          })

          //                          <======== don't need sort and limit stages 
          //                                    in photo detail so I removed it

          .lookup({
             from: 'users',
             localField: 'userId',
             foreignField: '_id',        
             as: 'createdBy',
          })
          .unwind('$createdBy')      
          .lookup({
             from: 'conversations',
             localField: '_id',
             foreignField: 'conversationId',       
             as: 'conversations',
          })
          .unwind({
             path: '$conversations',
             preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          })
          .project({
             _id: 0,
             id: '$_id',
             photoDescription: 1,
             photoUrl: 1,
             createdBy: '$createdBy',
             conversations: '$conversations',
             createdAt: 1,
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline is an array of objects. You can write:

```
const lookupStageA = {
             from: 'users',
             localField: 'userId',
             foreignField: '_id',        
             as: 'createdBy',
          };

const lookupStageB = {
             from: 'conversations',
             localField: '_id',
             foreignField: 'conversationId',       
             as: 'conversations',
          };
const unwindStage = {
             path: '$conversations',
             preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          };

const projectStage = {
             _id: 0,
             id: '$_id',
             photoDescription: 1,
             photoUrl: 1,
             createdBy: '$createdBy',
             conversations: '$conversations',
             createdAt: 1,
          };
```

Then you can use:

```
PhotoModel.aggregate()
          .match({ deleted: false })
          .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
          .limit(10)
          .lookup(lookupStageA)
          .unwind('$createdBy')      
          .lookup(lookupStageB)
          .unwind(unwindStage)
          .project(projectStage);
```

Or even:

```
const pipeline = [
  {$match: { deleted: false }},
  {$sort: { createdAt: -1 }},
  {$limit: 10},
  {$lookup: lookupStageA},
  {$unwind: '$createdBy'},      
  {$lookup: lookupStageB},
  {$unwind: unwindStage},
  {$project: projectStage}
]

PhotoModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Which you can manipulate using `if` statements with `push()` for example